How do you estimate MC error from a low-discrepancy sequence without using another simulation?
As asked in the question - for a pure random sample, we can estimate standard error by taking the sample standard and divided by square root of n due to IID assumption
If I generate $2^n$ samples of N dimension by Sobol. Can I say divide the $2^n$ samples by first half and second half? I assume no.
Is there anything I can do by looking at the MC mean of the first $2^{n-2}$ samples, $2^{n-1}$ and $2^n$ for example?
